# Makefile for java program that takes a file_name during run

Tags: java, file-io, makefile

I have been compiling and running my program on Ubuntu terminal like so :

> javac ev.java
>
> java xyz.class file_name.txt

How do I make a makefile for this?

I've been through some tutorials but they don't talk about the case where a file is included and frankly I haven't been able to make much sense of them anyway.

My `Makefile` so far:

```
all : build run
build : javac ev.java
run : java xyz.class
```

And no, I don't want to use ant, maven etc. Only Makefile.

Comment: Pure code-writing (and makefile writing) requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: added my work so far.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make this a complete example, start with a basic Java program such-as `Hello.java` here

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

We're going to then create a `Makefile`; we want to run `Hello.class` (and `Hello.class` *depends* on `Hello.java`). Let's add a compiler `OPTS` variable and a `CLASSPATH` variable as well (for this example, we'll just use `.` and enable debugging). Note that `make` gives tabs (and the whitespace in variable assignment) semantic meaning, and this example contains **tabs**.

```
CLASSPATH = .
OPTS = -g
run: Hello.class
    java -cp $(CLASSPATH) Hello

Hello.class: Hello.java
    javac $(OPTS) -cp $(CLASSPATH) Hello.java

clean:
    rm -f Hello.class
```